# JS and CSS image path

Tags: theming, 8

Do I need to hardcode the image path to JavaScript and CSS files?

```
#mydiv { background: url(http://example.org/themes/mytheme/image/bg.png); }
```

I cannot use `{{ base_path }}/image/bg.png` in .js and .css files, which works in a template file.

Is there better way than hard-coding?

Comment: Why would you use absolute path? Relative paths are always used in CSS. In JS, you should use drupalSettings and construct path from there or set it in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correct, no need to hardcode images: Add any image through the Drupal program itself via the API or background images via the css and a relative path:

For example, if your image is at theme/images, do `{background: url(images/image.png);}` or `{background: url(../images/image.png);}` if your css is situated in a folder of it's own inside the theme's folder.

You could filter or manipulate specific images with JS globally via a custom js file for your site [as explained here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167676/how-do-i-enable-a-custom-js-file-in-my-drupal-site).